# jsp - <c:import /> with server username and password

Tags: jsp

I have a simple jsp page that is trying to access another jsp file from another server

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:import url="http://our-other-server.com/header.jsp"></c:import>
```

As it's our sensitive QA site it's password protected from the server, can I add the username and password as parameters to ?  It's a tomcat server where the other site exists.  Without the credentials it throws a 500 error of course

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your environment uses HTTP `Basic` access authentication, you can basically add the credentials on the URL as follows:

```
<c:import url="http://username:password@our-other-server.com/header.jsp" />
```

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on HTTP Basic access authentication.

Comment: Thank you, is there an article / documentation I can read to find out more about this?