# 401 error while loading url from server side

Tags: java, websphere-8, http-status-code-401

A `Java webapp` hosted in `WebSphere`  which tries to load a url (html file) during start up. But it throws the error

```
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https/abc.com:10708/myjavaapp/html/customtemplate.html?lang=en
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1912)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1510)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:19)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireReader(ImportSupport.java:439)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:339)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:231)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._layout._jspx_meth_c_import_0(_layout.java:885)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._layout._jspx_meth_c_if_2(_layout.java:922)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._layout._jspx_meth_c_if_1(_layout.java:955)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._layout.doTag(_layout.java:298)
at _ibmjsp.WEB_2D_INF.jsp.reporting._reportview._jspx_meth_l_layout_0(_reportview.java:1994)
at _ibmjsp.WEB_2D_INF.jsp.reporting._reportview._jspService(_reportview.java:203)
```

But the url is accessible via browser. I know browsers send in authentication data  through headers when making http requests. But here the http request is generated from within the application through jsp using `<c:import url="${customTemplate}" />` where the `customTemplate` resolves into the above https url.

Another fact is that there are other files (css, js) getting loaded from the same location without issues. Only the html request is blocked. Could it be a filter that controls html file access on the web server?

Comment: Does the page normally need authentication to access? If so, how are you trying to authenticate?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö - Yes its a landing home page once the user successfully logs in through the login page.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853295/jsp-cimport-with-server-username-and-password